# Submitted user is also getting Reassign | Approve/Reject button on record

Tags: approval-process

I am new to Approval process and i am facing a problem and don't know why is this coming and how to fix this.

In my application opportunity has a field name is `PIC(user look up)` who can submit a record for approval. As per some criteria it goes to some other user for approval but the PIC who submitted the record for approval is also getting links like below -

```
Reassign | Approve/Reject
```

and he can `approve/reject` this record himself. These links should not be visible to him. How can i hide these link for submitted user.

**Edit :-**

I am submitting record for approval using Apex Code and i am using standard approval related list to display approval actions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think it would be useful if you added a screenshot of your approval process.

Comment: Seconding @PepeFloyd's comment.  It sounds like you have an issue with the configuration of your approval process (or perhaps your apex submission, though less like), please post a screenshot of your approval setup and a code snippet for the approval submisssion.

Comment: In the config of your approval process, who is your "Next Automated Approver Determined By" ?

Comment: And also what's the first step of your approval actions?

Comment: Check whether you assigned with modify all in Permission set of that Object.

Comment: Any findings here? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi @pramod Kumar, I am working on a similar solution that you have tried but I am getting the same issue what you have asked in your question. Could you please guide me on how to resolve this issue? Did you use any metadata API? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While creating approval process you must uncheck the Allow Submitters to recall approval requests in step 6. This will help you avoid Approve/Reject functionality .Below is the screenshot for the same .[image]

Comment: I am submitting through Apex

Comment: The Process belonging to object you are trying to submit needs to be edited and uncheck the checkbox shown above in screenshot. Then it will work . In apex code we dont create any new approval process , instead we submit the approval process associated to the object . Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok i got your point. This setting is checked in my configuration but as far as i have read only "Recall Approval Request" button should be visible in this case and that is being visible to submitter but why these 3 links are visible to him?

Comment: Verify whether you are system admin or not . If you are system admin then you can see the links.

Comment: no i am not sys admin

Answer (score 1):

It's only the submitter's profile that determine that whether he can approve or reject the records submitted for approval. Can you please confirm that you are not a system admin and can you please give it a try with a  normal standard user ?

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: I am not system admin and it is confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is not an admin then most likely the reason is that the user is a member of the queue/or group that is set as designated approver. Assuming that a single user was not selected in that field.

Comment: No there is no designated approver specified.

Comment: @PramodKumar: Why is that field blank?. I am just trying to understand what's the use case there...

Comment: Also, can you double check that the user doesn't have permission "Modify All Data", it doesn't matter if the profile is not "system administrator".

Comment: Yes i have checked that user neither have "Modify All Data" permission in profile or on object