# Approval Process Issue: Reassign and Approve/Reject Links are displaying for the submitter. Any thoughts please?

Tags: approval-process

My question could be a duplicate of another question that has been asked long back but without a concrete suggestion/solution.

[Submitted user is also getting Reassign | Approve/Reject button on record](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17911/submitted-user-is-also-getting-reassign-approve-reject-button-on-record)

I have created multiple approvals through Apex and submitted as a non-admin user.

But, the biggest issue is, I am still able to see Reassign and Approve/Reject links for the approvals which I have submitted.

Actually, those approval requests have to be handled by the users Jon and Park in this case.

Any thoughts on why I am getting Reassign, Approve/Reject links even I am being as a submitter. I can adjust with Reassign link but I do not want Approve/Reject links which are not meaningful. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

**Experts, please advise.** Thanks.

Code snippet:

```
            List<Id> approvers = new List<Id>{'005o0000000POyp','005o0000000POyo','005o00000033qPS','005o0000000POyn','005o0000001z4Qz','005o0000000P6Y0','005o0000000POyl','005o0000002mdGZ','005o0000000POzf','005o0000000PZSU','005o0000002H8kV','005o0000003ZFd0'};
            List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> appreqs = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();

            for (Id appId : approvers) {
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new 
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

                req.setComments('Need approval. Product sample quantity is beyond the limit.');
                req.setObjectId('006o000000GN07w');
                req.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{appId});

                appreqs.add(req);
            }

            List<Approval.ProcessResult> ApprovalReqs = Approval.process(appreqs);
```

Comment: did you logged in as integration user and taken this screenshot?

Comment: Yes, @SantanuBoral. I took this screenshot in sandbox. I logged in sys admin and logged in as integration user from Manage Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Us the Approval set to Unanimous and not First Approver for Approvals for this section of the Approval process?

> When multiple approvers are selected:

- Approve or reject based on the FIRST response.
- Require UNANIMOUS approval from all selected approvers.

If you look at the MetadataAPI for approval processes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm), specifically the section on ApprovalStepApprover that would give you the reference you need.  If you would like to modify the approval process from Apex you would need to download the one of the wsdl either developer or enterprise and then use the wsdl2apex tool in salesforce to generate a wrapper, or it would be easier to use [Andy Fawcett's](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) version of it where he already did most of the cleanup work.

Comment: Is that possible to set this through Apex? Because I have used apex to achieve multiple approvals as the standard point and click does not provide a way.

Comment: are you creating the approvals via apex and the metadata or are you processing (i.e. submitting records for approval) through apex?

Comment: i have created approvals via apex. The objective is the sales rep has to get approvals from respective product managers if their opportunity products exceeding the quantity limit. There could be many product managers for a product and a product can be managed by many prod managers and it is N-N relationship. Since, an opportunity can have multiple products, the approval request has to sent to many product managers for their approval.

Comment: do u mind posting a snippet of code for how you create the approval process, cause i get the feeling that I'm talking around what you really mean.  But if it is what you say then you need to set the ApprovalStepApprover.whenMultipleApprovers to RoutingType.FirstResponse because the default routing type is Unanimous

Comment: please see the updated question as i have added the code snippet.

Comment: Ok so you are submitting approval requests via apex not creating approvals.  So you have the approval process(es) already defined in salesforce, you need to edit the approval process defined in salesforce to  approve or reject on first response not Unanimous. There are no apex methods to do this exposed to the process classes.  To do this via code you would need to use the metadata api but in essence what you would be doing is editing the approval process via soap requests wrapped in apex code. You need to edit the approval process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be helpful if you suggests an article or sample code.

Comment: Added some references but you might also want to use a tool like soapui to import the wsdl and make the call to approval step routing type for your approval process